# Windows in-memory cache for enterprise

Tags: windows, memcached, enterprise, in-memory

Do you know any memcached analogue for using for enterprise in Windows. Any commercial in-memory cache system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Oracle?  Define your "enterprise" requirements, or just memcached on Windows?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/imdb-cache/index.html
 http://www.membase.com/products-and-services/memcached

Answer (score 4):

**A multi server in-RAM key-value cache usable from Windows?** Sure, in no particular order:

- [Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) (Windows, free with Windows Server licenses)
- [Shared Cache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/homepage.aspx) (Windows, open source)
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/) running on Linux boxes, using fx [Enyim as .NET client](http://memcached.enyim.com/) connector from Windows (open source)
- [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) (Windows, commercial and not cheap)
- [redis](http://redis.io/) running on Linux boxes with [Service Stack as .NET client](http://www.servicestack.net/) from Windows (open source)
- [ScaleOut StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/compare-products/) (Windows, commercial)

Answer (score 1):

If membase doesn't have some of the features, try one of these:

Microsoft's Server AppFabric (codename Velocity, NOT Azure AppFabric)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849

There's a 3rd party solution called ncache if you need an alternative:

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/

Answer (score 0):

We are in the process of transitioning from NCache (implemented a few years ago after comparing it to ScaleOut), to Membase (http://www.membase.com/) for cost and other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out also [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com) - Redis for Windows. It is a stable and production ready Windows port of Redis. The Developer Edition is free.